# WPF UserControl DependencyProperty is null in click event but not in binding

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a UserControl called ModuleButton. This UC has some DependencyProperties and some public ICommand properties. I am trying to get the button to execute the two ICommand's I have when the button is clicked and the checkbox is checked. However clicking them doesn't do anything.

I first was using the click events on both the button and the checkbox, however when calling the property "Module" it would say its  null. In the spirit of trying to do this as MVVM I moved them to RelayCommands thinking maybe its a DataContext issue. I know that the DependencyProperties are working because I am bound to them on the XAML side and everything looks fine. I even bound my checkbox text to display my "Module" property with a ToString converter as I was convinced that wasn't being bound properly, and it is. I haven't been able to find anything with my specific issue. I have a suspicion that it has to do with my ICommand properties aren't in the same context as my DependencyProperties.

**ModuleButton.xaml**

All the bindings work here except the none DependencyProperties bindings. I currently don't have the checkbox command bound as I'm trying to troubleshoot the button command first.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="50*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="20*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button Style="{DynamicResource BaseButton}" Command="{Binding ModuleButtonClickCommand}" Content="{Binding Text}" Margin="5"/>
    <DockPanel Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,0,0,4">
        <CheckBox VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="{Binding Module, Converter={StaticResource ToString}}" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Foreground="#FFE8E8E8" Margin="0" Style="{DynamicResource myCheckboxStyle}"/>
        <Image Source="/Resources/Info-24.png" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,5,0" ToolTip="{Binding Description}"/>
    </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```

**ModuleButton.xaml.cs**

RelayCommands are never executed, they work in other parts of my program that aren't mixed in with DependencyProperties.

```
public partial class ModuleButton : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Text", typeof(string), typeof(ModuleButton),
        new PropertyMetadata("Default Text")
        );

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DescriptionProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Description", typeof(string), typeof(ModuleButton),
        new PropertyMetadata("Default Description")
        );

    public static readonly DependencyProperty PageProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Page", typeof(Uri), typeof(ModuleButton),
        new PropertyMetadata(null)
        );

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ModuleProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Module", typeof(IModule), typeof(ModuleButton),
        new PropertyMetadata(null)
        );

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsCheckedProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "IsChecked", typeof(bool), typeof(ModuleButton),
        new PropertyMetadata(false)
        );

    public string Text { get => (string)GetValue(TextProperty); set => SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    public string Description { get => (string)GetValue(DescriptionProperty); set => SetValue(DescriptionProperty, value); }
    public Uri Page { get => (Uri)GetValue(PageProperty); set => SetValue(PageProperty, value); }
    public IModule Module { get => (IModule)GetValue(ModuleProperty); set => SetValue(ModuleProperty, value); }
    public bool IsChecked { get => (bool)GetValue(IsCheckedProperty); set => SetValue(IsCheckedProperty, value); }

    public event EventHandler FavoriteIsCheckedChanged;

    public ModuleButton()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        FavoriteCheckboxClickedCommand = new RelayCommand(param => FavoriteCheckboxClicked());
        ModuleButtonClickCommand = new RelayCommand(param => ModuleButtonClick());
    }

    public ICommand FavoriteCheckboxClickedCommand { get; private set; }
    public ICommand ModuleButtonClickCommand { get; private set; }

    private void FavoriteCheckboxClicked()
    {
        FavoriteIsCheckedChanged?.Invoke(this, new EventArgs() { });
    }

    private void ModuleButtonClick()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("ModuleButtonClick");
    }
}
```

This is the tab control its all displayed in.

```
<Page.DataContext>
    <viewmodels:MainToolPageViewModel/>
</Page.DataContext>
<TabControl x:Name="Tabs" Margin="5" ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs}">
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Content}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

This is how the Tabs list and its content area are populated.

```
var cats = ModuleManager.GetCategories();
foreach (var cat in cats.list.OrderBy(x => x.index))
{
    var buttonsHost = new ModulesButtonHostView();
    foreach (var mod in ModuleManager.LoadedModules.Where(x => x.Category == cat.name))
    {
        buttonsHost.Modules.Add(new ModuleItem {
            Text = mod.Name,
            Module = mod,
            Description = mod.Description,
            Page = mod.Page
        });
    }

    Tabs.Add(new MyTabItem() {
        Header = cat.name,
        Content = buttonsHost
    });
}
```

**ModulesButtonHostView.xaml**

Modules is a list of ModuleItems that have the same properties as the DependencyProperties on ModuleButton control.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Modules}" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <controls:ModuleButton/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel FlowDirection="LeftToRight"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

[image]

What I'm expecting to happen is when I click the Module Button, it is able to use the Module property to load that module, which I have that part of the code working, it's the actual using the Module property in the RelayCommand that I can't figure out why its null.

**Edit:**

Adding image of issue with binding suggestion

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should set the source or the `DataContext` of the bindings to the `UserControl` itself:

```
<Grid DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="50*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="20*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button Style="{DynamicResource BaseButton}" Command="{Binding ModuleButtonClickCommand}" Content="{Binding Text}" Margin="5"/>
    <DockPanel Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,0,0,4">
        <CheckBox VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="{Binding Module, Converter={StaticResource ToString}}" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Foreground="#FFE8E8E8" Margin="0" Style="{DynamicResource myCheckboxStyle}"/>
        <Image Source="/Resources/Info-24.png" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,5,0" ToolTip="{Binding Description}"/>
    </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```

If you don't, the runtime will look for these properties in the `ModuleItem` class.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Setting the datacontext that way makes it so the bindings to the commands work, but breaks the bindings to the DependencyProperties so it only shows defaults. I tried setting just the commands to the RelativeSource binding, and now my DependencyProperties are working and when I click the button, the command is executed, but it still thinks Module is null, even though its not, but I guess it is null in the context its looking at.

Comment: @Skint007: Well, it breaks the bindings to any dependency properties that are not defined in the `UserControl`. I though the `Module` was defined there. So what is your current issue?

Comment: They are defined in my `UserControl`. The problem is the commands aren't Dependency properties, they are local public properties on the `UserControl`, so they are in a different context it seems, as the context of the dependency properties seem to be the assigned ModuleItem. I'm wondering if need to add the commands to the ModuleItem and assign them from my ModuleButtonHostViewModel where the list of Moduleitem's are created.

Comment: @Skint007: No, it doesn't matter whether they are dependency properties. If you set the `DataContext` like I showed you, you can bind directly to any of its properties.

Comment: I did put the binding like you showed, and the command buttons did work, but it broke the bindings to the dependency properties and showed their default values instead, and also when trying to do anything with my `Module` property it said it was null. I've added a screenshot of what happens to the button when I put the binding the way you show.

Comment: @Skint007: You don't set the `Text` property of the `UserControl` to some value somewhere do you? `<controls:ModuleButton Text="{Binding SourceProperty}"/>`

Comment: I don't, it is set on the ModuleItem when I first create it and add it to the Modules list on the ModuleButtonsHostView. I did end up getting this to work, although not 100% happy, I basically added the commands as Dependency Properties also, and setup the RelayCommands during the ModuleItem creation. For now this will have to work lol.

Comment: Yes, but you still need to bind the property of the `UserControl` to the source property of the `ModuleItem`.